# Rose diagrams in Google Chart

Tags: python, google-visualization, histogram

I searched around for ways to make rose diagrams (circular histograms) in Google Chart. The API has only radar diagrams, so it seems not technically possible (am I correct?). This [wind rose example](http://www.carloslabs.com/node/18) was the closest I came to a solution.

Because I needed them, I figured out a way to fake them quickly using the Radar plots, Python and the [Google-Chartwrapper](http://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/) library. There's a (non-technical) [write-up available](http://positivelyglorious.com/software-media/wow-fully-functional-rose-diagrams-with-google-chart/) and the code is on [Github](http://github.com/Mettadore/PyGoogleRose).

**Before I take this further (i.e. clean code, abstract, waste more time, etc.), has anyone else seen examples of Rose diagrams in Google Chart that might be useful?**

(By the way, I know about matplotlib, etc. I'm using Python 3.x out of necessity and, as yet, the graphing libraries haven't caught up enough to use as I need them. See also SO question 418835))

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like no-one has any other examples. I DID decide to play around with this to see what else is possible and created a quick proof of concept for [time-based rose diagrams](http://rose-clock.mettadore.com). It's just a silly thing to show your relative Twitter posting amount by time of day, but shows how Google Chart can be used for rose diagrams. The problem here, and a problem in general that this has illustrated with Google Chart, is that you cannot have embedded data contained in the chart, with drill-down capabilities, popups, etc. (as you could with a Javascript/Flex/other solution).

It'd be nice if there were a Google Chart-style API that was javascript based to allow embedded data.